# Concurrent API call in thread in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test race condition of API through RSpec.
I have an employee table where employee_code need to be unique.
If there is more than one employee with same code, system will automatically add number with the code and it works. Now i want to test if it works when multiple same code employee try to create employee at the same time.

```
threads = []
wait = true
4.times do |i|
  threads << Thread.new do
    true while wait
    submit_request example.metadata
  end
end

wait = false
threads.each(&:join)
```

I have added a truncation config for this

```
config.around(:each, use_transactional_fixtures: false) do |example|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    example.run
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  end
```

And my specs are:

```
describe "concurrent create employee request", use_transactional_fixtures: false do
  before do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  after do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  context "multiple login enabled" do
    context "should save all" do
      let(:params) { { employee: { employee_code: "employee" } } }
      before do
        allow(Time.zone).to receive(:now).and_return(Time.zone.now)
      end

      before do |example|
        threaded_api_request(example)
      end

      it do
        expect(Employee.count).to eq 4
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But my problem is although all the threads are executing, But not all threads are calling the API which causing my specs failing(sometimes 2 or 3 times). Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: When your specs fail what error do you get? How does the code look like that you use to generate the unique codes? Do you have a unique index in the database to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @spickermann I get expected 4, got: 1/2/3
I set some log comment in my code both in controller and thread. i see thread comment is always printed 4 times but the comment in controller showed 1/2/3 times

I am using advisory lock as well as unique index with rescue block but i never go in the rescue block too

Answer (score 1):

I guess each `submit_request` will spawn a separate thread, so your test case will failed if 4 test threads done but some of `submit_request` threads have not done yet.

```
      thread1  thread2  thread3  thread4
wait    |         |        |        |
submit  -----------------------------------> request1 r2 r3 r4
        |         |        |        |           |      |  |  |
join    X         x        x        x          done    |  |  done
expect  failed since Employee.count = 2                |  |
```

as you can see, request threads r2 and r3 have not done yet, so there're only 2 employees are saved.

So (in case i guess correctly), you should make sure all `submit_request` threads done before expect result, if your `submit_request` have callbacks (or somehow you know when it done) perhaps you could use [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Mutex.html) + [ConditionVariable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/ConditionVariable.html), the more elegant way is to use [CountdownLatch from gem concurrency-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/atomic/mutex_count_down_latch.rb#L9) (Rails use this gem internal), you create a CountDownLatch with count 4, then whenever each of request thread done, you reduce the count, the rspec expectation only run when the count is zero.

```rb
latch = Concurrent::CountDownLatch.new(4)
4.times do |i|
  Thread.new do
     submit_request(example.metadata) do # done callback
       latch.count_down # -1
     end
  end
end

latch.wait # until latch.count == 0

expect(Employee.count).to eq 4
```